# Computing polygon outline vertices on the GPU

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7, xna, gpu

**I'm trying to draw 2D polygons with wide, colored outlines without using a custom shader.**
 (if I were to write one it'd probably be slower than using the CPU since I'm not well-versed in shaders)
To do so I plan to draw the polygons like normal, and then use the resulting depth-buffer as a stencil when drawing the same, expanded geometry.

**The XNA "GraphicsDevice" can draw primitives given any array of IVertexType instances:**

```
DrawUserPrimitives<T>(PrimitiveType primitiveType, T[] vertexData, int vertexOffset, int primitiveCount, VertexDeclaration vertexDeclaration) where T : struct;
```

**I've defined an IvertexType for 2D coordinate space:**

```
public struct VertexPosition2DColor : IVertexType
{
    public VertexPosition2DColor (Vector2 position, Color color) {
        this.position = position;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Vector2 position;
    public Color color;

    public static VertexDeclaration declaration = new VertexDeclaration (
        new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0),
        new VertexElement(sizeof(float)*2, VertexElementFormat.Color, VertexElementUsage.Color, 0)
    );

    VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration {
        get {return declaration;}
    }
}
```

**I've defined an array class for storing a polygon's vertices, colors, and edge normals:**
I hope to pass this class as the T[] parameter in the GraphicDevice's DrawPrimitives function.
The goal is for the outline vertices to be GPU-calculated since it's apparently good at such things.

```
internal class VertexOutlineArray : Array
{
    internal VertexOutlineArray (Vector2[] positions, Vector2[] normals, Color[] colors, Color[] outlineColors, bool outlineDrawMode) {
        this.positions = positions;
        this.normals = normals;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.outlineColors = outlineColors;
        this.outlineDrawMode = outlineDrawMode;
    }

    internal Vector2[] positions, normals;
    internal Color[] colors, outlineColors;
    internal float outlineWidth;
    internal bool outlineDrawMode;

    internal void SetVertex(int index, Vector2 position, Vector2 normal, Color color, Color outlineColor) {
        positions[index] = position;
        normals[index] = normal;
        colors[index] = color;
        outlineColors[index] = outlineColor;
    }

    internal VertexPosition2DColor this[int i] {
        get {return (outlineDrawMode)? new VertexPosition2DColor(positions[i] + outlineWidth*normals[i], outlineColors[i]) 
                                     : new VertexPosition2DColor(positions[i], colors[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**I want to be able to render the shape and it's outline like so:**
the depth buffer is used as a stencil when drawing the expanded outliner geometry

```
protected override void RenderLocally (GraphicsDevice device)
{
    // Draw shape
    mVertices.outlineDrawMode = true; //mVertices is a VertexOutlineArray instance

    device.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;
    device.PresentationParameters.DepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth16;
    device.Clear(ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.SkyBlue, 0, 0);
    device.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPosition2DColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, (VertexPosition2DColor[])mVertices, 0, mVertices.Length -2, VertexPosition2DColor.declaration);

    // Draw outline
    mVertices.outlineDrawMode = true;

    device.DepthStencilState = new DepthStencilState {
        DepthBufferWriteEnable = true,
        DepthBufferFunction = CompareFunction.Greater //keeps the outline from writing over the shape
    };
    device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, mVertices.ToArray(), 0, mVertices.Count -2);
}
```

**This doesn't work though, because I'm unable to pass my VertexArray class as a T[]. How can I amend this or otherwise accomplish the goal of doing outline calculations on the GPU without a custom shader?**

Comment: You should delete one post, you have created dupicated questions

Comment: @Cuong Le nice catch, deleted.

Comment: Um, I think you're under a misapprenhension here. GPUs are so amazingly blindingly faster than the CPU, you pretty much can't go wrong. In addition, it's sending things from CPU to GPU that's slow- you're taking the slowest route possible.

Comment: @DeadMG could I get a link on that? Any idea whether the XNA BasicEffect has to send such slow data anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why you dont simply write a class that draws the outline using pairs of thin triangles as lines? You could create a generalized polyline routine that receives an input of the 2d points and a width of the line and the routine spits out a VertexBuffer.

I realize this isn't answering your question but I cant see what the advantage is of trying to do it your way. Is there a specific effect you want to achieve or are you going to be manipulating the data very frequently or scaling the polygons alot?

---

The problem you are likely having is that XNA4 for Windows Phone 7 does not support custom shaders at all. In fact they purposefully limited it to a set of predefined shaders because of the number of permutations that would have to be tested. The ones currently supported are:

AlphaTestEffect
BasicEffect
EnvironmentMapEffect
DualTextureEffect
SkinnedEffect

You can read about them here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203872(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

I have not tested creating or utilizing a IVertexType with Vector2 position and normal and so I cant comment on if it is supported or not. If I were to do this I would use just the BasicEffect and VertexPositionNormal for the main polygonal shape rendering and adjust the DiffuseColor for each polygon. For rendering the outline you use the existing VertexBuffer and scale it appropriately by calling GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject() to determine the 3d coordinate distance require to produce a n-pixel 2d screen distance(your outline width).

Remember that when you are using the BasicEffect, or any effect for that matter, that you have to loop through the EffectPass array of the CurrentTechnique and call the Apply() method for each pass before you make your Draw call.

```
        device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        device.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
        device.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;

        //Set the appropriate vertex and indice buffers
        device.SetVertexBuffer(_polygonVertices);
        device.Indices = _polygonIndices;

        foreach (EffectPass pass in _worldEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();
            PApp.Graphics.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, _polygonVertices.VertexCount, 0, _polygonIndices.IndexCount / 3);
        }
```

Comment: There will be a lot of scaling and mutations, and I want an effect that can be applied to any rasterized, orthogonal geometry

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to as orthogonal geometry; is that just a technical term for your polygons rendered parallel to the viewport of an orthogonal projection?